# Double measurement frequency

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which can be abstract as

```py
>>> pd.DataFrame({'time':[1,2,3], 'data':[10,20,30]})
   time  data
0     1    10
1     2    20
2     3    30
```

I want to "double" the time column by adding rows midway between each pair, and interpolate for the data column.

The expected result for the example data would be

```py
   time    data
0     1      10
1     1.5    15
2     2      20
3     2.5    25
4     3      30
```

**Note**: "time" will not necessarily be evenly spaced, another equally valid dataset could be

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({'time':[1,2.1,3], 'data':[10,20,30]})
   time    data
0     1      10
1     2.1    20
2     3      30
```

As such, I don't think something like `resample` would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to `.reindex` + `.interpolate`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':[1,2.1,3], 'data':[10,20,30]})

df.index = df.index * 2
df = df.reindex(index=range(0, df.index.max()+1)).interpolate()

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   time  data
0  1.00  10.0
1  1.55  15.0
2  2.10  20.0
3  2.55  25.0
4  3.00  30.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using `np.linspace()`

```
m = df.index.max()

df = df.reindex(np.linspace(0,m,(m*2)+1)).interpolate().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   time  data
0   1.0  10.0
1   1.5  15.0
2   2.0  20.0
3   2.5  25.0
4   3.0  30.0
```